# bug in package cutwin?

Tags: cutwin

I'm learning how to use package cutwin. I copy the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74702/247085:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\opencutleft
\begin{thm}
\begin{cutout}{2}{0pt}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}{6}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{cutout}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

but I can't get the same result as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74702/247085, the picture is some lines higher than expected:
[image]

I'm using TexLive 2021, compiling the above code via XeLaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: updated cutwin now at ctan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An updated cutwin is now available on ctan (2021-10-31) and will be in tex distributions shortly, so the original answer below is no longer applicable.

---

Cutwin apparently needs some updates (An interaction with the new picture mode implementation in latex) until then you can roll the format back to a compatible version

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[2020/02/08]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\opencutleft
\begin{thm}
\begin{cutout}{2}{0pt}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}{6}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{cutout}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2021-10-31

cutwin has been updated on ctan and the patch is no longer needed

---

### Old Answer

`cutwin`  uses the length `\@tempdimc` in two places without being able to be sure that it isn't changed between the two uses -- and picture now does exactly this. The code works again if cutwin uses its own temporary length:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\cut@tempdimc
% patch twice:
\patchcmd\pageinwindow{\@tempdimc}{\cut@tempdimc}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\pageinwindow{\@tempdimc}{\cut@tempdimc}{}{\fail}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\opencutleft
\begin{thm}
\begin{cutout}{2}{0pt}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}{6}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{cutout}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

This is a clear bug in `cutwin` (and it should change its use of `\@tempdimb` too, this isn't safe either).

Comment: I am unable any longer to support the `cutwin` (or any other of my packages/classes). Is anyone willing to take them over?

Comment: @PeterWilson thanks, in this case we might change latex again so as not to affect cutwin or we could with the above permision make the register rename in cutwin and upload to ctan

Comment: @PeterWilson I have a fixed version here that I could push to ctan https://github.com/davidcarlisle/cutwin

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you kindly. You have my permission to do what you think is best (but it seems a bit drastic to change latex because of an old package, unless other packages are, or maybe, also affected by the latex upgrade).

Comment: @PeterWilson well it's always a slight question with \@tempwhatever names if two things both use the same register who to blame but the suggested change in that github link just renames the register at cutwin so wouldn't need a chanege in latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would be very pleased if you pushed your github version to ctan. Any chance of you adding your name to the documentation (as maintainer????). Will R. is the maintainer of practically all of my packages, except that he only very rarely does. We're hoping for a new volunteer.

Comment: cutwin updated on ctan